# Why does VIM changes encoding of all buffers when using setlocal?

Tags: vim

When I'm using `setlocal encoding` on VIM to change the buffer encoding VIM changes the encoding of all buffers. It's really annoying because I'm editing files in different encoding and I'm corrupting them all the time. I tried it by creating two buffers, did a `setlocal encoding=latin1` on one, a `setlocal encoding=utf-8` on the other : the encoding is always the same on the two buffers and it's always the last encoding I set.

`setlocal` works well on 'shiftwidth' for example, the issue only exhibits on the encoding option.

I tried to reinstall a new copy of VIM, I tried the 7.2 and 7.1, I still have the issue. I've disabled all my plugins, my vimrc.

Am I losing my mind thinking that it's the way it used to work ? Do you have some idea that might cause that ?

I'm using VIM on Windows 7 if that's important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`'encoding'` is a global option that dictates how Vim treats text internally so you are two times wrong.

1. `setlocal` doesn't work for global-only options like `'encoding'`.

   `:help 'option'` tells you the "scope" of `'option'`.
2. `'encoding'` is not the option you are looking for, you want `:set fileencoding=utf-8`.

Reference:

```
:help 'encoding'
:help 'fileencoding'
:help 'setlocal'
```

Comment: I clearly hadn't understood that. Also I read some of you VIM other answers, lot of awesome VIM things. Thank you.